# deploy jquery or javascript front-end project

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, web-frontend

I use [adminlte](https://adminlte.io/) admin template for my admin panel project.
[adminlte](https://adminlte.io/) is developed with jquery, javascript, and bootstrap.
I developed a project with separate front-end and back-end layers, which means my front-end project is just jquery and javascript and backend is .net core. When I want to publish the front-end layer, I just copy files on the server. I want to know, is this the correct way?

One of the problems is that the browser caches javascript files and when I copy the new version on the server, browsers loads previous versions. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your import, you can use param like ?=xxx and change this value when you have new version of this js

```html
<script src="js/XXX.js?v=1">
```

next time if you want to update that

```html
<script src="js/XXX.js?v=2">
```

Comment: maybe even smarter is to have version stored in a file, and change it only there, then use variable in src

Comment: @den, exactly, I used the same method, but the browser doesn't understand this, sometimes.
I want to know if there is a way to publish all the files together in a package or not, like deploy a vue-js or react project

Answer (score 0):

I do know on firefox and chrome you can disable caching by going to the network tab on the developer panel and click the disable cache button [firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfb8Z.png) [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZui5.png)

Comment: yes, this work will be done with CTRL + F5 on the browser, but this problem was solved just for me.
users should not be involved with this problem

Comment: @mohsenahmadi who are you using to host your services, some will cache but have the option to turn it off temporarily for development mode